# How to record game in FIFA 12 without screencapturing?

Tags: fifa-12

How to record whole game in FIFA 12 without using screencapturing software (FRAPS and etc.)? Is it possible at all?

Comment: I suppose, if the game doesn't support saving of replays, you could plug your video and audio output into some sort of pass-through recording device, but that's probably not what you're looking for.

Comment: @kotekzot yeah, I am looking for in-game feature.